# How can i remove the file path on my list and only display the text files?

Tags: python

currently I have this list

```
log_list =
['C:\Users\Me\Downloads\archive108\archive\tools\Fors\JuniorLogFile.txt', 'C:\Users\Me\Downloads\archive108\archive\tools\Fors\SeniorLogFile.txt', 'C:\Users\Me\Downloads\archive108\archive\tools\Fors\BasicLogFile.txt', 'C:\Users\Me\Downloads\archive108\archive\tools\Fors\PrimaryLogFile.txt', 'C:\Users\Me\Downloads\archive108\archive\tools\Fors\IntermediateLogFile.txt']
```

I tried using

```
log_files_split = [i.split("s")[4] for i in log_files]
```

but the code doesnt work on other pathfiles how can i always have the output list to contain only the text files shown below

```
['JuniorLogFile.txt', 'SeniorLogFile.txt', 'BasicLogFile.txt', 'PrimaryLogFile.txt', 'IntermediateLogFile.txt']
```

Comment: What on earth do you want here?  Tell us the overall goal.

Comment: You meant `i.split("\\")[-1]`?

Comment: Backslash is an escape character so i'm not sure if your paths are correctly interpreted by python but if they are you could use patlib and create path objects with you current path and then use .name attribute to get only the name of your files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply you can use `os` package as follows -

```py
import os

log_list = [
    r'C:\Users\Me\Downloads\archive108\archive\tools\Fors\JuniorLogFile.txt',
    r'C:\Users\Me\Downloads\archive108\archive\tools\Fors\SeniorLogFile.txt',
    r'C:\Users\Me\Downloads\archive108\archive\tools\Fors\BasicLogFile.txt',
    r'C:\Users\Me\Downloads\archive108\archive\tools\Fors\PrimaryLogFile.txt',
    r'C:\Users\Me\Downloads\archive108\archive\tools\Fors\IntermediateLogFile.txt'
]

file_names = [os.path.basename(file_name) for file_name in log_list if os.path.exists(file_name)]
print(f'File names - {file_names}')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import ntpath
def path_leaf(path):
    head, tail = ntpath.split(path)
    return tail or ntpath.basename(head)

paths = [r'C:\Users\Me\Downloads\archive108\archive\tools\Fors\JuniorLogFile.txt', r'C:\Users\Me\Downloads\archive108\archive\tools\Fors\SeniorLogFile.txt']
pathlist = [path_leaf(path) for path in paths]
```

pathlist variable will give you only text file .